# Why is my NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods get called randomly when creating a relationship with my entity?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm having trouble debugging a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` behavior.

My `NSFetchedResultsController` has a fetch request concerning a `Object1` entity. Whenever a cell is touch, I create (and save) a new relationship to a `Object2` entity (or use if it exists already).

My problem is that `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` gets called randomly when such a relationship is created (meaning, sometimes it gets called, sometimes it doesn't).

My code creation the relationship is using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord):

```
+ (void)createOrUpdateRelationship:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                             forObject1:(NSManagedObject1 *)object1 {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        NSManagedObject2 *object2 = [NSManagedObject2 fetchObject2ForObject1WithID:object1.ID
                                                                                       inContext:localContext];
        if (!object2) {
            object2 = [NSManagedObject2 MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
            object2.createdAt = [NSDate date];
        }

        object2.updatedAt = [NSDate date];
        // Store attributes from userInfo

        object2.object1 = [object1 MR_inContext:localContext];
    } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
        // Celebrate
    }];
}
```

Any idea what I could do wrong?

Comment: You must be having inverse relationship as well from object 2 to object 1 isnt it ???

Comment: Absolutely. I have both ways of the 1-1 relationship set up.

Comment: Bear in mind that if object2 already exists, and is related to another Object1 object (say "oldObject1"), then *three* objects are updated: object2, object1 *and* oldObject1 (its relationship will be set to nil).  Does that explain the random behaviour?

Comment: Thank. Updates don't explain the random behaviour. I thought about it and the behavior is random for creations only. (for updates, the delegate never gets called, which sounds fair enough)

Answer (score 0):

Dirty Henry,

Object1 is having a one to one relationship with Object2 and Object2 has inverse relationship with Object1 as well :)

So whenever you change the relationship value of any of these objects other object will also be modified :) Hence NSFetchedResultsController gets triggered :) Thats quite common :)

You cant skip these changes from being triggered.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
      switch(type) {
             case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
             //you might consider ignoring it but I wont prefer that though :)
             break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry if my question is not clear: i have no problem with the delegate being called. My problem is that, when the relationship is created, sometimes it gets called and sometimes it doesn't. And I need to know why.

Comment: @dirty-henry : I dont work with magical records much can you please confirm when you say sometimes it triggers and sometime not the relationship that you establish on local context is synced to main context ??? Or saved to persistent store ???

Comment: Absolutely. The local context is created as a child of the main context and saves happen (1) on this child/local context and (2) on the parent/main context.